# Reserved Routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, laravel-5

I am moving from Codeigniter to Laravel so whenever I can't find anything in Laravel I look back to codeigniter, Laravel has a pretty intense route mechanism. In Codeigniter there are some reserved routes like

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controller_name';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Are there any reserved routes in Laravel, the one I assume is

```
Route::Auth();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no reserved routes in Laravel, you just define the ones you want.

`Route::auth()` just sets up the required routes for the included authentication - if you're not using them then you don't need to define them.

Comment: auth() is a complete package which we download from packagist and install, if we have anyother package like auth(), will we use its route just like this. Route::package()

Comment: Nope, `Route::auth()` comes from Laravel's default authentication library. It is not provided by a third-party library. If you use a third-party library for authentication it will provide another mechanism for registering it's routes.